# Cannot refer the font files that were uploaded in a server in my local html file

Tags: html, css, fonts, webfonts

I have to refer some font files in my html pages. The problem is the font files are uploaded in an server. So i need to refer to an external font files.

In my html page through font face i am importing the font file that has been on an server.

Unfortunately i cannot paste the code

Answer (score 0):

Linking to external font files is difficult, so what you could do is copy the font files from the server so you can link to them locally.

If you don't have FTP access to the server, you could use web inspector > network > fonts. Copy the URL for each font file, then open and save it from your web browser.

Once you've downloaded them, you can link to them locally.

Hope this helps!

[image: web inspector > network > fonts]